# getting error code message is not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Iv been working on this bot which when you type "/court @user time" it will give them the role jail
and after the given amount of time it will remove it but when i run it it doesn't work and it says:
"discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined"

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re
import time
from time import sleep

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as', bot.user)
    channel = bot.get_channel(717005397655027805)
    #await channel.send("I am now online")
    activity = discord.Game(name="eb!help", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

@bot.command(name='court')
@commands.has_role('Server Developer')
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned, time):
    messageContent = message.content
    if len(messageContent) > 0:
        if re.search("^send.*court$", messageContent):

            user_id = message.mentions[0].id
            user = message.mentions[0]

            await message.channel.send(
                f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
            )

            role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
            await user.add_roles(role)

            sleep(time)

            await bot.remove_roles(user, role)

bot.run('TOKEN_GOES_HERE')
```

Comment: The error is clear, you try to access `message` but you don't have a variable called `message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear,
`messageContent = message.content`.
`message` isn't defined in the scope here.
We can get the message with `ctx.message`

```py
@bot.command(name='court')
@commands.has_role('Server Developer')
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned, time):
    message = ctx.message
    messageContent = message.content
```

Doing this will work fine, but you're entirely misusing `ext.commands` here.

You could do

```py
@bot.command(name='court')
@commands.has_role('Server Developer')
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    await user_mentioned.add_roles(role)
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await user_mentioned.remove_roles(role)
```

`time.sleep` is blocking and `bot` doesn't have the attribute `remove_roles`, please refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for information.

Comment: i get no errors but the bot doesn't respond or do anything

Comment: There isn't any response in the above code, try doing a `ctx.send` somewhere in the function to get a response

Comment: i did do it still no respoce and it doesent add the role

Comment: You might not have permissions, the above code works. I tested it on my bot.

Comment: it has administrator premitions

Comment: iv managed to fix the help command by adding this to the end:
`
await bot.process_commands(message)
`
but the court command still doesn't work

Comment: try printing something to check if it was invoked.

Comment: it doesn't print anything i uploaded a comment on the post it on the post it self to show you the court command current status

Comment: Did you run `$court @asafmeizner`?

Comment: i run ```$court @my_disocrd_username 10```

Comment: hello @ceres why are you not answearing

Comment: the command works for me, with the exact code you provided.

Comment: weird then why does it not work for me did you remove a part or edit something?

Answer (score 0):

@ceres here's the court command code:

```
bot.command(name='court')
@commands.has_role('Server Developer') 
async def court(ctx, user_mentioned: discord.Member, time: int):
    print("test")
    user_id = message.mentions[0].id
    user = message.mentions[0]
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    await user_mentioned.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(
        f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    await user_mentioned.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get message's content by typing `ctx.message.content` but you don't need it. If you describe the parameter as `discord.Member`, it will return a member object if it founds else bot will raise `commands.BadArgument`. Also you should use `asyncio.sleep` for async sleep. This will not block your bot's other commands.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command(name='court')
@commands.has_role('Server Developer')
async def court(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
    if role is not None:
        await ctx.send(
            f"sending {user.mention} to court!"
        )
     
        await user.add_roles(role)

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        await user.remove_roles(role)

    else:
        await ctx.send("Role `Jail` is not exist.")


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: the bot runs for a second then closes